# c# get next execution datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, scheduled-tasks

I have the following code:

```
Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<TimeSpan>> Daily = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<TimeSpan>>();
```

The idea is that i can add a day with a time to the Daily dictionary. But a job can execute on the same day more than once.

so Daily can look like this:

```
{ "Monday" : [{"Hour":10, "Minute": 15}, {"Hour": 8, "Minute":5}] }
```

Now i would like to get the next execution datetime.

```
private void UpdateNextExecutionTime()
    {
        TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(15, 15, 0);
        DayOfWeek current = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

        DayOfWeek tmp = current;
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);

        int cur = (int)current;
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if(Daily.ContainsKey((DayOfWeek)cur)) {
                tmp = (DayOfWeek)cur;

                /* stuck */

                continue;
            }

            cur++;
            if (cur >= 7)
                cur = 0;
        }
    }
```

I managed to get the first upcoming day (including today) in the Daily dictionary but i'm stuck on the getting the time.

How would i be able to do this?

Comment: Why not use `System.TimeSpan` instead? I do not see a need to try to roll your own type.

Comment: That said, it is not clear what you are trying to do. Show the code you have so far.

Comment: @Igor Replaced custom type with Timespan, hope the added code makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: You can use `DateTime.TimeOfDay` to get the `TimeSpan` that represents the time part of the `DateTime` instead of creating one using all the individual parts.

Comment: Maintain the list of `TimeSpan`s in sorted order (or sort them once when the list is complete), then retrieving the next one is just bumping the index. However, you're probably going to write a bunch more code related to scheduling, and it's not all trivial. Consider using an existing solution, like [this](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/) or (if you don't mind overkill) [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `t` is the time you're using as the point at which you'd like to find the next execution time, put this where you have 'stuck' (edit; just realized you changed to using `TimeSpan` in your list):

```
var execTimes = Daily[tmp];
if (execTimes != null) {
    var nextTime = execTimes.OrderBy(x => x).FirstOrDefault(x => x > t);
    if (nextTime != default(TimeSpan)) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the day in the TimeSpan,

Here is a simple example the finds the next date:

```
var schedule = new List<TimeSpan>{
    new TimeSpan(0,16,30,0),
    new TimeSpan(1,16,30,0),
    new TimeSpan(5,16,30,0)
};

var monday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 1);
var fromMonday = DateTime.Now - monday;
var next = schedule.OrderBy(t => t).FirstOrDefault(t => t > fromMonday);

Console.Write(monday + next - DateTime.Now);
```